# How to record audio with gstreamer in time intervals

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

Basically my question is somewhat same to this one: [How to record audio in gstreamer for pre-defined time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253064/how-to-record-audio-in-gstreamer-for-pre-defined-time)

But there is no answer which i can use there and i'm also relatively new to using gstreamer. Using the code in the question posted by the other user what can i add to record the audio in time intervals of x seconds with pauses of y seconds between each capture.

Comment: the answer there seems to be correct, just try it out. the guy who answered is gstreamer developer.

Comment: I don't understand how to use the provided information. Could you help me?

Comment: Here's another one with a somewhat same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103221/sending-eos-in-gstreamer-after-pre-defined-time-using-new-single-shot-id?rq=1 and again without a elaborate answer for a beginner.

Comment: When you need to stop the recording (at given time interval) I guess you just send eos to the pipeline which will flush remainng data into your recording sink and stops the pipeline - thus stops recording process. what part of this you dont understand? please post some of your code and we may find some way how to send the eos signal in your code..

Comment: here's the code http://pastebin.com/4AN44LhG